# SAP Passport public CA certificate

Tags: certificate, sap-basis

Is there a Public SAP Passport Root Certificate I can use to import into an SAP system so that we could use SAP Passports as Logon certificates?

I would like to test a SAP Passport in a DEV ABAP system and need the to import the Public root Certificate first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAP Passport root certificate can currently be downloaded from [here](https://tcs.mysap.com/invoke/tc/getCert?SAPPassportCA.der). Should that link no longer work, an updated link should be on the [SAP Trust Center Services](https://support.sap.com/en/offerings-programs/support-services/trust-center-services.html) site.

I've just installed that root certificate and verified that it is the one used to sign SAP Passports.

Comment: as it turns out the is an option inside STRUSTSSO2 that offers the option to use the sap passport cert. However, the link you provided also works and is currently the same certificate.  Thanks MJ